# Why does response time increase with throughput?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, parallel-computing

I'm seeing this pattern that the response time increases as throughput increases, and that the throughput has a peak after the response time starts rising. This seems counter-intuitive. It seems like as the response time starts to rise, the throughput should flatten out due to queuing or simply exhaustion of resources.

Is it related to synchronization? More clients, more threads etc.

Why does this happen?

Here's an example from oracle:
[image: throughput-response time graph]
And a few more from google searches:
[image: throughput-response time graph 2]
[image: throughput-response time graph 3]

Comment: Decreasing performance on the same input using more processors is indeed a common theme in parallel computing. That said, the particular issues are numerous. You don't give any detail so this is impossible to answer with any certainty. Note also that the third dimension (the input) is missing from the plots. Since it's unrealistic to demand any system to scale to arbitrarily many cores *on a single input*, the plots may not be telling you the story you want.

Comment: Only the first graph shows a peak for the throughput. The others only
show flattening.

Comment: You may have answered this question yourself.  When throughput is low, which can be thought of as an internal population demanding service, there are no queues.